# Why inherit the Tits systems structure by a $B$-adapted homomorphism?

Tags: gr.group-theory, geometric-group-theory, coxeter-groups, local-fields, buildings

Let $(G,B,N,S)$ be a Tits system and $\phi\colon G\longrightarrow \hat{G}$ a $B$-adapted in the sense of the paper [Groupes réductifs sur un corps local: I](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1972__41__5_0) of Bruhat–Tits. They said that $\phi$ is a $B$-adapted homomorphism if $\phi$ satisfies
the following conditions;

1. $\operatorname{Ker}\phi\subset B$, and
2. for any $ g\in \hat{G}$, there exists $h\in G$ such that $g\phi(B)g^{-1}=\phi(hBh^{-1})$.

Then any parabolic subgroup $P$ of $G$ and $g\in \hat{G}$, the subgroup ${}^{g}P=\phi^{-1}(g\phi(P)g^{-1})$ is also a parabolic subgroup of $G$. So $\hat{G}$ acts on the set of parabolic subgroups of $G$. Write $\operatorname{Stab}(P)=\{g\in \hat{G}\mathrel{\vert} {}^{g}P=P\}$.

They provides a homomorphism $\xi\colon \hat{G}\longrightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(W,S)$ such that
$$
\phi(C(\xi(g)\cdot w))=\phi(h)^{-1}g\phi(C(w))g^{-1}\phi(h)
$$
for all $h\in G$ (satisfies $g\phi(B)g^{-1}=\phi(hBh^{-1})$) and $w\in W$, where $C(w)$ is a Bruhat cell $BwB$). Write $\hat{G}_{0}=\operatorname{Ker} \xi$.

I have two questions;

1. why is the restriction $\xi\rvert_{\operatorname{Stab}(B)}\colon \operatorname{Stab}(B)\longrightarrow \operatorname{Im} \xi$  surjective?
2. why is $(\hat{B},\phi(N))$ a $BN$-pair of $\hat{G}_{0}$? Here $\hat{B}=\hat{G}_{0}\cap \operatorname{Stab}(B)$.

These questions are written in Bruhat–Tits's  "[Groupes réductifs sur un corps local: I](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=PMIHES_1972__41__5_0)" without proof.　I thought about this all day today, but I couldn't prove it.

Comment: Should the equation concerning $\phi(C(w))$ mention $\xi$ somewhere?

Comment: Thank you. It's a careless mistake.

Comment: I can prove 1. For any $g\in \hat{G}$, there exists $h\in G$ such that $\phi(h^{-1})g\in {\rm Stab} B$. Since $\phi(G)\subset \hat{G}_{0}$, we have $\hat{G}=\hat{G}_{0}\cdot {\rm Stab} B$. Thus the restriction of $\xi$ to ${\rm Stab} B$ is surjective.

Comment: Now I proved a part of 2. The intersection $\phi(N)\cap \hat{B}$ is normal in $\phi(N)$. For any $x,y\in N$ such that $\phi(x)\in \hat{B}$, we have $\phi(xBx^{-1})=\phi(B)$ from the definition ${\rm Stab} B$. So we have $\phi(xb_{1}x^{-1}b_{2})=0$ for any $b_{1}\in B$ and some $b_{2}\in B$. Since ${\rm Ker}\phi\subset B$, $xb_{1}x^{-1}b_{2}\in B$. As $N_{G}(B)=B$, this means that $x\in B\cap N (\triangleleft N)$. Then we have $\phi(yxy^{-1})\in \hat{B}\cap \phi(N)$. Thus $\hat{B}\cap \phi(N)\triangleleft \phi(N)$.

Comment: TeX note: please use, e.g., $\operatorname{Ker} \phi$ `\operatorname{Ker} \phi` instead of $\rm Ker \phi$ `\rm Ker \phi`; particularly note the spacing.